# How can i group by my model into multiple table in django as below?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say i have this table:

```
| Name   | Age | Country |
--------------------------
| A      |  17 | England |
--------------------------
| B      |  18 | Swiss   |
--------------------------
| C      |  19 | Italy   |
--------------------------
| D      |  19 | Italy   |
--------------------------
| E      |  19 | England |
-------------------------
```

as any column will contain distinct value like in this example country column contain 3 distinct value **(England, Swiss, Italy)**
as well as age **(17, 18, 19)**

And i want django query to sort the table by the country column as follow:

```
>England

| Name   | Age | Country |
--------------------------
| A      |  17 | England |
--------------------------
| E      |  19 | England |
--------------------------

>Italy

| Name   | Age | Country |
--------------------------
| C      |  19 | Italy   |
--------------------------
| D      |  19 | Italy   |
--------------------------

>Swiss

| Name   | Age | Country |
--------------------------
| B      |  18 | Swiss   |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with regroup https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: Is this regroup can work in queryset?